# What does func( arg: (type1, type2) => Future[Any]) mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I came across some code in Scala like:

```
 def props(factory: (TransactionId,
                      String,
                      ImageName,
                      Boolean,
                      ByteSize,
                      Int,
                      Option[ExecutableWhiskAction]) => Future[Container])
```

What does the param `factory` having multiple data type imply and what is the name or definition of this property of Scala and how does it work?

Comment: That is just a **function** that is a pretty basic concept, I would recommend you to follow any basic tutorial to the language.

Comment: `props` is a function that takes another function (`factory`) as its argument. `factory` itself is a function with a bunch of arguments of types given in the argument tuple which returns `Future[Container]`. You can then call `factory` inside `props` just as you would call any other function.

Comment: @HristoIliev actually `props` is a **method** that recieves a **function**.

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html

Comment: let me be clear, here the type of `factory` is declared as a tuple of multiple data types and classes, can someone explain what this means?

Comment: @ShariarKabir the type of `factory` is not a tuple, it's a function from tuple to future. Return type of `props` is not specified and there is no implementation of `props`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I feel calling `factory`'s input a single tuple might confuse the OP. It's really a `Function7` taking 7 different arguments and returning a `Future`.

Comment: @user right, tuple to future would be `((..., ..., ...)) => Future[Container]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def props(factory: (TransactionId,
                    String,
                    ImageName,
                    Boolean,
                    ByteSize,
                    Int,
                    Option[ExecutableWhiskAction]) => Future[Container])
```

Let's unpack this definition from outside-in.

`def props(x: A)` defines a function or method (depending on the particular context) named `props` which takes an argument `x` of type `A`.  In this case, since no result type is defined (we don't have `def props(x: A): B`), the result type is inferred by the compiler.

We can then expand:

- `x` to `factory`.  The argument is bound to `factory`.
- `A` to `(TransactionId, String, ImageName, Boolean, ByteSize, Int, Option[ExecutableWhiskAction]) => Future[Container]`

`factory` is a value like any other.  In this case `(TransactionId, String, ImageName, Boolean, ByteSize, Int, Option[ExecutableWhiskAction]) => Future[Container]` is just another way of saying (this translation is performed by the compiler):

```
Function7[TransactionId, String, ImageName, Boolean, ByteSize, Int, Option[ExecutableWhiskAction], Future[Container]]
```

Any object which is an instance of this type can be passed to `props`.  There's only one method of interest for this type:

```
def apply(x1: TransactionId,
          x2: String,
          x3: ImageName,
          x4: Boolean,
          x5: ByteSize,
          x6: Int,
          x7: Option[ExecutableWhiskAction]): Future[Container]
```

What this type represents is a function from 7 arguments of the given types (I'm not going to name them again, in the interest of brevity) which results in a `Future[Container]`.

In short, we have a function/method (for our purposes, there's no difference here, and the code given doesn't say whether we're dealing with a function or a method) which takes a function as an argument.  This makes it a higher-order function: in a language like Scala where functions are "first-class" values like, say, an `Int`, the uses of higher-order functions are almost limitless.

In this case, what this basically means is that the `props` function/method (or some other function/method it delegates to) has some means of getting a `TransactionId`, a `String`, an `ImageName`, a `Boolean`, a `ByteSize`, an `Int` and an `Option[ExecutableWhiskAction]` and you, the caller of `props` can provide a way to get a `Future[Container]` of your choosing from those values and `props` will (if it decides to: just like any function, `props` could decide (e.g. if there's an error somewhere) not to use an argument you've passed it) use that if it needs a `Future[Container]`.

How can you create a `Function7`?

- You can explicitly extend it:

```
val x: Function7[...] = new Function7 {
  def apply(...): ... = ???
}
```

or

```
object MyFactory extends Function7[...] {
  def apply(...): ... = ???
}
```

- More idiomatically in many situations, you can use a lambda expression which the compiler translates into something very similar to the first bit of code above:

```
{ (x1: TransactionId, x2: String, x3: ImageName, x4: Boolean, x5: ByteSize, x6: Int, x7: Option[ExecutableWhiskAction]) =>
  // some code that results in a `Future[Container]`
}
```

- If you have some `foo` object which has a method `bar` which takes the appropriate arguments and has an appropriate result

```
foo.bar _
```

Comment: _"defines a function or method (depending on the particular context)"_ a `def` always creates a **method**, period.

Comment: Odersky et al disagree with you: _Programming in Scala_ (3rd edition), p. 28: "Function definitions start with `def`".  p. 143, meanwhile defines method as a function defined as a member of some object (at the level of the language, not at the level of the implementation).

Comment: The language tries very hard to make **functions** and **methods** the same, but they are so different in Scala 2 that they need to be differentiated _(Hopefully Scala 3 will reduce this number of differences until the point the only relevant one will be implementation details)_. I think of inner `def` as _method private methods_ (is a not a formal term, I known) because they still aren't values, they can have default values for their arguments, they can be generic; functions have all the opposite characteristics.

Comment: You can use idiosyncratic definitions all you want, but you kind of forfeit the right to say "period" in such contexts.

Comment: You do not have to be rude when I wasn't. A **function**, in Scala, is an instance of one of the `FunctionN` classes, a `def` don't do that. - Yeah I get that the word function is overloaded in the programming context, that is why in **Scala** is very important to make the distinction.

Answer (score -3):

Ok I think I got it now. As LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez said `props` takes a function as an input. Upon further exploration, I found that `factory` is nothing but a template for the Lambda functions `props` takes as input. Thank you all

Comment: A lambda `x => f(x)` shouldn't be confused with a function type `X => Y` (["This is not a pipe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images)). `X => Y` is not a "template" for `x => f(x)`. Just Scala uses the same symbol `=>`, they could be different: `x :=> f(x)`, `X =>: Y`. A lambda `x => f(x)` has a type `X => Y` but a type `X => Y` is inhabited by not only lambda terms `x => f(x)`.